# How to get Dataframe partitions to include literal colons instead of encoded (%3A) colons in S3 key names

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In pyspark, I have a dataframe that contains a date column with the date truncated to the day

```
# +-------------------+                                                           
# |d                  |
# +-------------------+
# |2018-04-07 00:00:00|
# +-------------------+
```

When I do this:

```
df.write.partitionBy('d').parquet('s3://somebucket/out/')
```

... I expect to find key named like:

```
s3://somebucket/out/d=2018-04-07 00:00:00/part-*-c*.snappy.parquet
```

... But, instead, I find this:

```
s3://somebucket/out/d=2018-04-07 00%3A00%3A00/part-*-c*.snappy.parquet
```

(note the '%3A' instead of ':')

This wreaks havoc on the athena/hive/etc partitions.

Is there a way to get pyspark to use a real colon instead of encoding it as %3A?

Comment: How about changing the date format? In fact, you don't even need the time information, so you can simply get rid of that part...

Comment: @ErnestKiwele - Sure.  Can you specify the date format in the .partitionBy?  Or is it best to do that in a select on the dataframe before doing the write?

Comment: I'd simply change the data type of the column if it's a time stamp, or change the format if it's a string. Yes, before calling `.write`